# Lazy loading generator for training a Keras network

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

A common use for Keras LSTM layers is to generate text. There are
[many examples](https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) showing you how to do it.

The usual method is to convert the text into a sequence of tokens and
then slice up the sequence into overlapping windows which is used as
inputs and the windows following tokens are the outputs.

So if your token sequence is of length `i` and the length of each window
is `j`, the input data would have the dimensions `(i, j)`. The output data
would have the dimensions `(i)`. But then you also have to one hot
encode the data. So if the number of unique tokens is `k`, the input
gets the dimensions `(i, j, k)` and the output `(i, k)`.

This is way to much data to fit in memory. So you have to load it
iteratively, using a generator. Here is my generator that does that:

```
class OneHotGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, seq, batch_size, win_size, vocab_size):
        self.seq = seq
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.win_size = win_size
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size

    def __len__(self):
        n_windows = len(self.seq) - self.win_size
        return int(np.ceil(n_windows / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        base = i * self.batch_size

        # Fix running over the dge.
        n_windows = len(self.seq) - self.win_size
        batch_size = min(n_windows - base, self.batch_size)

        X = np.zeros((batch_size, self.win_size, self.vocab_size),
                     dtype = np.bool)
        Y = np.zeros((batch_size, self.vocab_size),
                     dtype = np.bool)
        for i in range(batch_size):
            for j in range(self.win_size):
                X[i, j, self.seq[base + i + j]] = 1
            Y[i, self.seq[base + i + self.win_size]] = 1
        return X, Y
```

Meant to be used like this:

```
gen = OneHotGenerator(seq, batch_size, win_size, vocab_size)
model.fit_generator(generator = gen,
                    steps_per_epoch = len(seq) // batch_size,
                    ...)
```

where `seq` is the sequence of tokens. The code works (I think), but
I'm not happy with it for a few reasons:

- Windowing a sequence and converting it to one hot vectors seem like
  a very common use case. There should be something in Keras that can
  do what I want so I don't have to write the code myself.
- I haven't double-checked all indexing operations. There may be some
  unhandled edge cases.
- My `__getitem__` code doesn't seem to be very efficient. It seem to
  slow down training quite a bit.
- The code doesn't handle different step sizes (the amount of overlap
  between windows) or any edge cases.

So what I want to know is if there is a better way to do what I want?
If it isn't can my code be improved?

Comment: Your example doesn't actually show usage, all it shows is that variables can be passed to functions. Usage would be using `len(gen)  # ???` and `gen[1]  # ???`, or `for foo in gen:`.